# Cant resolve constructor ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview

Can't use ArrayAdapter in a custom dialog.

[This is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yGN5.png)

[image]

Comment: Are you using the correct OnClickListener?

I notice that name has an OnClickListener yet below it, credit uses a View.OnClickListener

Comment: Yes, but that's not the problem here.

Comment: I know that which is why I made a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting that error because the `ArrayAdapter` constructor requires the first argument to be a `Context` object. Since you're calling the constructor from inside an `OnClickListener`, `this` refers to the listener, not your activity (i.e. not a `Context`).

You can qualify the `this` keyword with the name of your outer class. Assuming that code is written inside of `MainActivity`, you could write `MainActivity.this` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using `this` won't work since you are in the scope of the `OnClickListener`.

**You should try `getContext()` or `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`.**

Comment: The thing is i m using a different layout b.xml to show a dialog in layout a.xml. And i dont know the code for arrayadapter which i write in a.xml will work in b.xml.